# Having trouble with JComboBox and JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcombobox, classcastexception

Basically I am writing a simple TCP-UDP multiclient GUI and my program is throwing an error at the following part of the program. I have a `JComboBox` which has elements `TCP` and `UDP`. So if the element `TCP` is selected and I press `connect` then I should able to make a call to the `TCPconnection`method but it is not doing that. It is throwing an error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    javax.swing.JButton cannot be cast to javax.swing.JComboBox
```

Please help me!

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String command = e.getActionCommand();

    JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
    Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
    String comboItem = selected.toString();
    System.out.println(comboItem); //GOOD!
    if(comboItem.equals("TCP"))
    {
        isTCPconnection = true;
        if(isTCPconnection)
        {
            System.out.println("TCPconnection is true"); //GOOD!
        }
    }
    if(comboItem.equals("UDP"))
    {
        isUDPconnection = true;
    }

    if(command.equals("connect") && isTCPconnection) //PROBABLY HERE!
    {
        TCPconnection(serverName,serverPort);
        System.out.println("TCPconnection");
    }
    }
```

Comment: This is the action listener for your button, yes?

Comment: @KevinAnderson yes......

Comment: Well, `e.getSource()` is your button, then.  So the line `JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();` is trying to cast a `JButton` to a `JComboBox`. That's the error.

Comment: @KevinAnderson How do I fix it?

Comment: @KevinAnderson I need to say `if(command.equals("connect") && isTCPconnection)`

Comment: Somewhere in your program there is must be a variable that references your combo box.  Just use that variable when invoking `getSelectedItem()`. And of course get rid of `JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();`

Answer (score 0):

You added actionPerformed on a JButton (probably apply), not combo box.
Get JComboBox from the class not from source.